# Can I prevent an iPad app ever being updated?

Tags: ipad, applications, software-update, skype

The latest version of Skype for the iPad has commercials. It will probably be necessary to upgrade at some point, but until then I want to stay with the commercial free version.

Is there any way I can prevent it ever being updated? I want to ensure that it will not be updated by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back up your iPad with iTunes. Back up that hard drive. Unplug that backup and store it far away from any internet connection. If you do update Sykpe by mistake, restore the iPad from the backup. It won't keep Skype from updating, but it will preserve your ability to undo the update.

Comment: To put it a bit less dramatic, just store a copy of `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/Skype*.ipa` somewhere else. If you upgrade by accident, delete Skype from the iPad and iTunes, sync once, copy the saved version back to `Mobile Applications` and sync again.

Comment: I stick things like this on Dropbox. Also note that if you DO accidentally overwrite it, you might be able to find it in your Trash if you haven't emptied it.

Answer (score 2):

Just **drag the Skype icon from iTunes to your desktop** (or every other location for that matter) and you are all set.

Next time you get an update simply drag Skype from your desktop back into iTunes and you will have the original version again.

But for your original question: no it is not possible to prevent updates if you clicked the 'download all updates' button